# RAM Upgrade not working

Tags: windows-8, memory, motherboard

My motherboard is a Gigabyte GE-H55M-S2H and I was running 2 x 2gb DD3 pc3-10666 but I wanted to upgrade to 8gb so I bought an Adata DDR3 1600 PC3-12800 8gb. Now when I attempt to start the computer it loads onto the first window and says it's checked for memory and then after 5-10 seconds the computer shuts down, beeps, and repeats the process.

Any idea what could be wrong? From what I read, my mobo supports this new 12800 so I don't know what's going on? Do I need 2x4gb rather than 1x8gb and leaving the other port empty?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you check your motherboard's [official memory support list](http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/Memory/mb_memory_ga-h55m-s2h.pdf) first (via [here](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3310#dl))? That list is kept up to date. I don't see the 8GB adata on there. My guess is you need 2x4GB. The [specs](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3310#sp) say 2 slots w/ 8GB total but don't specify if a single 8GB is acceptable, however I would imagine it is not given the support list. Order two 4GB's from that list.

Comment: reseat your ram, and run memtest and the windows memory diagnostics. make sure they report all your ram and don't find any errors.